# Zero's before Store Numbers in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I recently got a spreadsheet from a vendor with a list of store numbers that I need to use for a crystal report that I am running.  Store numbers are 5 digits, most with at least one leading zero, and it has to match this way or crystal will not accept this field as compatible with the field I am attaching it to.  I highlighted the column and clicked format field and then clicked on custom and typed up 5 zeros, which did the trick, however, it is treating it like it is a zip code when it is not and therefore, when trying to link to another field in another program on crystal it is telling me that the fields are incompatible because it is showing up as a zip code instead of just the text.  Can anyone help me with trying to do this?  I dont want to have to format everything to text to add zero's to the beginning of 6000+ store numbers.  I just want to be able to do this quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [text function](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx) to convert them

`=TEXT(A1, "00000")`